# can't adjust header/footer width to text width APA6 class

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, apa6

I'm using the `\documentclass[doc]{apa6}` class to create a document, I decided to use the `fancyhdr` package but can't make it work, I tried with packages `anysize` and `geometry` but still not working.[image: Picture] Previos Picture shows an example of my problem.

I have try:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%\usepackage{anysize} % Para el margen
%\marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{1cm}{3cm}
\geometry{paper=a4paper,left=40mm,right=20mm,top=30mm, bottom=30mm}
```

but none of the two possibilities (the one active and the other commented work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code and package names](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. Also, if you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192), they'll be marked as a code block. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Also, if you add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, it will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the geometry, then call `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper,left=40mm,right=20mm,top=30mm, bottom=30mm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```